# Jenkins Using checkout scm to clone repo from Github

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, checkout, jenkins-template-engine

**Overview:**

- I am trying to checkout the github code in my multi-configuration jenkins pipeline:

  ```
  package checkout
  void call() {
      println "checkout stage ..."
      node {
          deleteDir()
          checkout scm
      }
  }
  ```
- I am using JTE (Jenkins Template Engine)

**ISSUE:**

But jenkins complains error `Step checkout from the library checkout does not have the method call(GitSCM)` after building the pipeline. Please find the stacktrace below:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.boozallen.plugins.jte.binding.TemplateException: Step checkout from the library checkout does not have the method call(GitSCM)
    at org.boozallen.plugins.jte.binding.injectors.StepWrapper.invoke(script1596520065305271654461.groovy:98)
    at org.boozallen.plugins.jte.binding.injectors.StepWrapper.call(script1596520065305271654461.groovy:60)
    at checkout.script15965200672531305703678.call(script15965200672531305703678.groovy:19)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor515.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.constructorCall(DefaultInvoker.java:25)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:97)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor632.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:107)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor632.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:89)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor632.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
```

As I am new in groovy and Jenkins, I would appreciate it if you could share any genuine solution or idea.

Answer (score 3):

I found my issues and will post it here to be used by newbies like me:

I needed to do following changes and rerun the jenkins build to fix the issue:

1. Move the `node` keyword to the template jenkinsfile in `/templates/jenkinsfile`

   ```
   node('<executer node>') {
    scm_checkout()
   }
   ```
2. Update the pipeline_config.groovy file in `/templates/`directory:

   ```
   libraries {
     merge = true
     scm_checkout
   }
   ```
3. Update the library directory name to scm_checkout. the directory and file name should be different form checkout to avoid referring the `checkout(scm)` to the wrong lib.
4. The checkout lib should in `libraries/scm_checkout/scm_checkout.groovy` and the content is like below:

   ```
   void call() {
       println "checkout stage ..."

       deleteDir()

       def checkout = checkout(scm)


   }
   ```